# Port isn't closing when I Exit out of a server

Tags: node.js, express, server

Hello everyone So I have this annoying problem where my port isn't closing. For example I'm using an express generator to give me an outline/skeleton of a node js/express server.

```
Port 3000 is already in use
```

Usually I would just able to CTRL + Z and it would exit out the server.

But recently it wasn't exiting out of the server completely.

I found a little work around which was this

```
lsof -wni tcp:3000
```

It would then generate something like this

```
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    5623 viet   12u  IPv6  59797      0t0  TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)
```

I would locate the PID and then kill it with this command

```
kill -9 5623
```

But now it just becomes quite annoying doing this over and over everytime I exit out of a server. Does anyone know why its doing this or I guess why CTRL Z wasn't working how It used to.

Comment: are you using linux?

Comment: @NewbeeDev yes ubuntu 14.04 specifically

Comment: Note that CTRL-Z **does not exit out of a program** on unix. It simply puts that program in the background (similar to starting the program with `&`). After you CTRL-Z you can get back into the (running, not exited) program by typing `fg`. You may have been mislead by the message `Stopped program_name` when you press CTRL-Z. It is stopped but not exited. What it means by "stopped" is that it is sleeping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ctrl+Z in Unix-based operating systems just suspends the application.

If you do

```
ps aux|grep node
```

and then

```
kill -9 processid
```

you should be able to reclaim the port.

Going forward, Ctrl+C to shut down the application.

Comment: This seems good. However beware of using the -9 signal for kill

Comment: `Ctrl-Z` doesn't put a process in the background, it pauses it (by sending it a `SIGTSTP` signal).

Comment: Or just `killall processname`, e.g. `killall node`.

Comment: @robertklep you are correct.  Sorry, that's what I meant; & puts it to the bg.  I've amended my answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @DaveMelia I'm such a noob lol. That explains why it was working a long time ago because I was doing CTRL C that time and now I then I was using CTRL Z to exit out. haha thank you

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
sudo fuser -k 3000/tcp
```

Comment: Sorry it didn't do anything. I ran my server. CTRL Z and ran it again and it logged out Port 3000 is already in use

Comment: It gave me a list of things though. HUP INT QUIT ILL TRAP ABRT IOT BUS FPE KILL USR1 SEGV USR2 PIPE ALRM TERM
STKFLT CHLD CONT STOP TSTP TTIN TTOU URG XCPU XFSZ VTALRM PROF WINCH IO PWR SYS
UNUSED

Comment: I don't really know what any of them mean though

Comment: I think your port is closed. but It just opens again for some reason

Comment: are you using foreverJS?

Comment: Nope justing using a simple Express-generator and running npm start